# General Solution of an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous function.

Can anyone please help me out to find the solution of the ODE: 
$$y\left( \frac{dy}{dx} + a y + b\right) = f(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} + a y + b = \frac{f(x)}{y}$$
Let $\quad y(x)=\frac{1}{u(x)}\quad\to\quad -\frac{u'}{u^2}+\frac{a}{u}+b=u(x)f(x)$
$$u'=a\,u+b\,u^2-f(x)u^3$$
This is an Abel's differential equation of the first kind. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel_equation_of_the_first_kind

The solvability depends on the kind of function $f(x)$. https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2011/387429/#sec2

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a closed-form solution in general, or even in some simple special cases such as $f(x)=x$.